# Rxjs to implement a live mailing

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

my code is pretty simple:

At the page loading I load the user's messages, then i want to merge all new incomming messages.

```ts
   this.me$ = this.store
        .pipe(map((state: AppState) => state.auth));

    const allMessages$ = this.me$
        .pipe(mergeMap((me: User) => this.messageService.getMessage$(me.username)));

    const allNewMessages$: Observable<Message[]> = this.me$
        .pipe(mergeMap((me: User) => this.messageService.newMessage$(me.username)))
        .pipe(scan((messages: Message[], newMessage: Message) => messages.concat(newMessage), []))
        .pipe(startWith([]))

    this.messages$ = combineLatest([allMessages$, allNewMessages$])
        .pipe(map(([allMessages, allNewMessages]) => allMessages.concat(allNewMessages)))
        .pipe(map((messages: Message[]) => [...messages].sort((d1, d2) => new Date(d1.date) < new Date(d2.date) ? -1 : 1)));
```

The problem is when new message is emitter the allNewMessages$ observable emit like:

```
events[m1, m2, m3] -> emitted[[m1], [m1, m1, m2], [m1, m1, m2, m1, m1, m2, m3]]
```

and I want something like:

```
events[m1, m2, m3] -> emitted[[m1], [m1, m2], [m1, m2, m3]]
```

thank you

Comment: Could you please create a StackBlitz? If I were to only consider the 3rd _paragraph_, everything should work as expected. Also, in your _diagram_, `events[m1]` is the message emitted from `me$` and `emitted[[m1]]` is what `allNewMessages$` emits ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. I have to replace my `mergeMap` in favor of `switchMap` in this way the Http observable are well unsuscribed and avoid multiple chaotic calls.